# Using int(.) to get rid of decimals

Tags: python, integer

I came across the following strange result in Python (I use Spyder environment). Any idea what is going on? And how can I fix this? I truly don't want to put 20 zeros in front of my variable nor using numpy for such a simple work makes sense!

```
int(121212000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
Out[27]: 121212000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

```
int(121212*1e20)
Out[28]: 12121199999999999802867712
```

---

```
int(121212*10e20)
Out[29]: 121211999999999993733709824
```

Comment: This isn't weird. `121212*1e20` creates a float. Fixed size, binary floating point representations  have inherent limitations to their precision. In this case, you can just do `121212*int(1e20)`, or, just do `121212*10**20`

Comment: Thank you Jab, that answered my question! I think I should learn more about floats and their limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with floating point precision.

You can use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/decimal.html) module like so:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(121212) * Decimal('10e20')
Decimal('121212000000000000000000000')
```

For more info, see the following [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Sorry, this is not a general soultion.  With `Decimal(10e20)` you are instantiating `Decimal` from a float. Try it with a different (higher) power and see what happens. Also you are out by a factor of 10. (`Decimal(121212) * Decimal('1e20')` would be okay - or just `Decimal('121212e20')`)

Comment: True, I didn't mind about the specifics, but it is the solution to his issue. I edited my answer a little.